# Update already existing item in database using RedBean

Tags: database, sql-update, redbean

Once again i'm turning to the stack community to try and solve my problem.
I'm using **Slim**, **Twig** and **RedBean** together to create a backend app for my website (long story short, i'm using Slim to be able to connect an API and an application to it).

(Note: I'm relatively new to RedBean so i'm not yet at ease with it)

However, i'm getting a strange exception error from a try and catch when trying to update a user.

The following points however work:
- Add user
- Delete user

When i update my user, it gives me the message "This email is already in use" which is normal since i'm it's the account's email. However, i cannot get passed the error...

Here is exception file (Models/Validation/Users.php):

```
class Users extends SimpleModel {

    public function update() {
        $firstname = trim($this->bean->firstname);
        $lastname = trim($this->bean->lastname);
        $email = trim($this->bean->email);

        if(isset($this->bean->firstname)){
            $firstname = trim($this->bean->firstname);
            if(empty($firstname)) {
                throw new ValidationException( 'You have to provide a firstname.' );
            }
        }

        if(isset($this->bean->lastname)){
            $lastname = trim($this->bean->lastname);
            if(empty($lastname)) {
                throw new ValidationException( 'You have to provide a lastname.' );
            }
        }

        if(isset($this->bean->email)){
            $email = trim($this->bean->email);
            if(empty($email)) {
                throw new ValidationException( 'You have to provide an email.' );
            }
        }

        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new ValidationException( 'Not a valid email.' );
        }

        $searchUser = R::findOne( 'Users', ' email = ? ', [ $email ] );
        if(!empty($searchUser)){
            $equal = $this->bean->equals($searchUser);
        } else {
            $equal = FALSE;
        }

        if(!empty($searchUser) && !$equal) {
            throw new ValidationException( 'This email already exists.' );
        }   
    }
}
```

And the update call:

```
public function update( $id, $entry ) {
        try {
            $user = R::load( $this->config->getTable('users'), 'id = ? ', [ $id ] );
            if(array_key_exists('firstname',$entry)) $user->firstname = $entry['firstname'];
            if(array_key_exists('lastname',$entry)) $user->lastname = $entry['lastname'];
            if(array_key_exists('email',$entry)) $user->email = $entry['email'];

            (!empty($entry['password'])) ? $user->password = password_hash($entry['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT) : null;

            R::store($user);

        } catch(ValidationException $e) {
            $this->errors[] = $e->getMessage();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

The put controller:

```
Class PutController extends Controllers\Controller {

    public function updateRecord() {

        $user = new Users($this->configManager('Database'));
        $this->data['user'] = $this->app->request->post();
        $password = trim($this->app->request->post('password'));
        $passwordConfirm = trim($this->app->request->post('password-confirm'));
        if((!empty($password) || !empty($passwordConfirm)) && ($password != $passwordConfirm)){
            $this->app->errors += ["Password and the confirmation are different"];
            return;
        }
        $user->update($this->args['id'], $this->app->request->post());
        $this->app->errors += $user->getErrors();

    }


}
```

And finally the route:

```
$this->app->group('/update/:id', function () {

        // Display the page to update a user
        $this->app->map('/', function ($id) {
            $data = new Users\GetController( 'updateView', ['id' => $id] );
            $data->send("Users/update.template.html");
        })->via('GET');

        // Post request to update a user
        $this->app->map('/', function ($id) {
            $data = new Users\PutController( 'updateRecord', ['id' => $id] );
            if(!empty($this->app->errors)) {
                $this->app->flashNow("errors", $this->app->errors);
                $data->send("Users/update.template.html");
            } else {
                $this->app->flash("success", "Successfully updated the user.");
                $this->app->redirect('../');
            }
        })->via('POST', 'PUT');

    });
```

And last but not least, the twig form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                    <input value="{{user.firstname}}" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                    <input value="{{user.lastname}}" type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input value="{{user.email}}" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">New password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password-confirm">Confirm your password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password-confirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
            </form>
```

I have no idea how to get past this error. I've tried adding freeze(true) but it did not work.

Same thing for debug, i set it to true/false and nothing changed.

If anybody has tips on how to solve this, i would be extremely greatful !

Thank you!

Comment: A better solution would be to check that the new email address is the same of the user (for the given id). If not and it is already there, you should show the error.

Comment: Hello Davide, thanks for your answer! I was actually trying to keep the use of the "equals" in RedBean. But thanks to you, i actually went back to the way the function works. What was wrong is that the type for the bean searched and the new bean (updated) was not the same: the existing type was 'Users' (capital) and the new one 'users'. Silly mistake that is now solved. Thanks for your answer anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my problem on my own with Davide's comment that sparked an idea.
It was a silly mistake: The equals() function from RedBean actually checks for the bean's type and that's where the problem was.

One of my bean had the type 'Users' (with capital) and the other 'users' (no capital) which was causing the exception.

Thanks to Davide for the spark! :)